# "confirming the screen lock on your old phone"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "[confirming the screen lock on your old phone](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.androidcentral.com/how-transfer-data-your-old-android-phone-your-new-phone%3famp)"? To me "to confirm" means "to support or establish the certainty or validity of; verify", but does it make sense to apply this definition in this context?

Comment: Thank you all very much for your explanations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This instruction appears to be the focus of your query.

> **Hit Next to confirm the screen lock on your old phone**

The instruction tell you that clicking on the NEXT option on the screen will take you to another screen where you can enter the screen-lock of your old phone as part of the process you are engaged in.

**Confirm** in this context means that you need to enter the screen-lock pin/formula/code to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

A "screen lock" in this context is the code and as such can indeed be confirmed, although I'd mean by this - inputted!

When you confirm something you say that it is correct or valid, you assure the endpoint that everything is in order.